# Call Non-Static method in Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I can't seem to figure out how to call a Non-Static method (Instance Method) From reflection.  What am I doing wrong? Really new / ignorant with reflection (If you haven't noticed):

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("Reflection.Order" + "1");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        object[] paramsArray = new object[] { "Hello" };
        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Handle", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public);

        method.Invoke(instance, paramsArray);

        Console.Read();
    }
}



public class Order1
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Order 1 ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your assembly (or dll) have Reflection.Order1 class? Does the class has Handle() function? Does it accepts an argument? I suppose the current executing assembly is the one you are referring to.If that is the case Order1 does not accept any arguments and Entire code wrapped inside the namespace Reflection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Your BindingFlags are incorrect. It should be:

   ```
   MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Handle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
   ```

   Or you can remove the binding flags all together and use the Default Binding behavior, which will work in this case.
2. Your `Handle` method as declared takes zero parameters, but you are invoking it with one parameter (`"Hello"`). Either add a string parameter to Handle:

   ```
   public void Handle(string something)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Order 1 ");
   }
   ```

   Or don't pass in any parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public
```

in your call to `GetMethod()`.

`BindingFlags.InvokeMethod` (and other invocation flags) is not used by `GetMethod()`. You can see what it's meant for in [the documentation for `Type.InvokeMember()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: Nope, that's not necessary. Just removing `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod` or the `BindingFlags` parameter altogether works.

Comment: @Inerdial You would *have* to include `BindingFlags.Instance` if any other binding flags are specified. `BindingFlags.Public` alone will not work.

Comment: @vcsjones Ah. My bad, I just tested without any flags and made a bad assumption.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the binding flags already mentioned, you appear to be trying to pass an argument to a method that doesn't take any.